# QGIS 2.0 Catchment areas by using a 1 hour walking time

Tags: qgis, catchment-area

i would like to have catchment areas around my points which show the area of an one hour walk. I looked around and found information about using the hiking funktion for calculating a distance with the new plugin "walking time" and found instructions for catchment areas using a road network. But i couldn't find a solution for getting the zone which lies around an 1 hour walk of my starting point (using something like the hiker function and not road systems!). Is there anyone who could help me?

Comment: How far could one walk in 1hr?

Comment: Can you clarify: you want to compute catchment areas based on a cost raster?

Comment: "How far could one walk in 1hr?" This is what for example toblers hiking function can tell me by using slope as costs. But so far i only could calculate this for a route from one single point to another. What i would like to have is an area around one point which is reached within this walking time. So it is based on a cost raster indeed.